# Sharepoint: Only view user created items in a custom list

Tags: moss, wss, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I have Sharepoint 2007 Standard and am using a Custom List to create a simple form. I only want all the users to view thier own created items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to go into list settings/advanced settings and set the item level permissions. If you just change the view someone could still access the item through another channel.

Comment: @Rick: I've done just this. Setup a list workflow so that whenever an item is created / updated you strip out the contributor permissions of the new item and reassign them against the new author using an impersonation step. Additionally, add a column to the list for "Private" and then add a second workflow to add "viewer" rights to the the general user group depending on whether the author tick the yes / no value.

Comment: @BrianScott may i know why following your approach would be a better option than to just change the advanced settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to your lists settings, scroll right down to the bottom and create a view, in the view you will find a section called "filter" select "Created By" is equal to "[Me]"